# How to make a json variable a php variable?

Tags: php, json

just learning about json. I have a php script here that gets Google's sample geocoding json results, and I'm wondering how I can take a part of that result and make it into a php variable. Here is what I have :

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true");
echo $data;

?>
```

That shows a JSON string with many keys and values. I'm wondering how I can take the LAT and LON out of the JSON and turn them into $lat and $lon, usable in php.

Thanks, Sam

Comment: Did you try searching for "json" in the PHP documentation?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) to convert it to a PHP data structure, then access it like any other PHP data structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'some json blah blah';
$array = json_decode($string, true); // Second param turns it into a full array, not an array of objects

echo '<pre>', print_r($array), '</pre>'; // echo it out
```